# Mondrian/Saiku - Closure Table - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku, transitive-closure-table

I am currently doing a PoC and facing a problem with closure table. I am using Saiku CE and database is postgres. Everything works until I add a closure table.
If I remove closure table hierarchy, I don't get any error. If keep it I get the error. I have created my demo schema using Foodmart.xml which I downloaded from Saiku itself.

Some forums suggested that it's an open bug with Mondrian but if it is then why same syntax works with foodmart? Is it a problem with Saiku CE? If I use Saiku EE (Trial version) for my PoC then will it work?

11:54:17,900 WARN  [RolapUtil] Mondrian: Warning: JDBC driver sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver not found
11:54:17,902 WARN  [RolapUtil] Mondrian: Warning: JDBC driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found
11:54:18,728 ERROR [SecurityAwareConnectionManager] Error connecting: ersdemods
java.lang.NullPointerException

```
<Dimension name="Organisation" key="Org Id">
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute name="Par Org" table="org_organisation" keyColumn="parent_id"  />
        <Attribute name="Org Id" table="org_organisation" keyColumn="id" nameColumn="name"   />
        <Attribute name='Country Name' table='org_organisation' keyColumn='country' hasHierarchy='false' />
        <Attribute name='County Name' table='org_organisation' hasHierarchy='false'>
            <Key>
                <Column name='country' />
                <Column name='county' />
            </Key>
            <Name>
                <Column name='county' />
            </Name>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute name='City Name' table='org_organisation' keyColumn='city' hasHierarchy='false' />
    </Attributes>
    <Hierarchies>

        <Hierarchy name="Organisations" allMemberName="All Organisations">
            <Level attribute="Org Id" parentAttribute="Par Org" nullParentValue="NULL">
                <Closure table='organisation_closure' parentColumn="closure_parent_org_id" childColumn="org_id" />

            </Level>
        </Hierarchy>

         <Hierarchy name='Oragnisation Location' allMemberName='All Org Location'>
            <Level attribute='Country Name' />
            <Level attribute='County Name' />
            <Level attribute='City Name' />
        </Hierarchy>
    </Hierarchies>
</Dimension>
```

Regards,
Puneet Tayal

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this issue.  Dimension definition was correct however dimension with closure table should be declared within the cube. 
If you declare them outside of the cube you would get this idiotic error. 
Looks like a bug with Mondrian 4.

Regrads,
Puneet Tayal